# The size of the array while getting the value from the function

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy

while passing the `points = convert2xy(scan)` to the function where scan is 5000x1040 2D array i am getting the error.

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes
> (5000,1040) (5000,)

```
def convert2xy(scan, fov=260, min_dist=0.02):
 
    angles = np.radians(np.linspace(-fov/2, fov/2, len(scan)))
    points = np.vstack([scan*np.cos(angles), scan*np.sin(angles)]).T

return points[scan>min_dist]
```

Comment: `angles` created from the `linspace` is a1d array with shape (5000,).  It needs to be (5000,1) shape to do the following multiplications.  You may need to read up on `broadcasting`.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the error message it is because you are multiplying `scan` which is of size (5000, 1040) with `angles` which is (5000,) within your vertical stack. Do you want to multiply each value of `angles` with the corresponding row of `scan`? If so, you could do `scan * angles[np.newaxis,:]` and therefore have `points` as follows:

```
points = np.vstack([scan*np.cos(scan * angles[:, np.newaxis]), 
                    scan*np.sin(scan * angles[:, np.newaxis])]).T
```

Comment: The function would remain the same but i need to change the line when i am calling the function.

Comment: If that is a question, then yes exactly.